# Javascript add a value to a selectbox

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

In my project I have an HTML like this one:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Coverage</label>
    <select id="t_cov_e" class="form-control">
       <option>API</option>
       <option>Architecture</option>
       <option>Database</option>
       <option>OS</option>
       <option>Web</option>
       <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Credits (Price)</label>
   <select id="t_price_e" class="form-control">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>6</option>
       <option>9</option>
       <option>12</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Well, when I select a table above I want to populate the display value of the selectbox in my code with clicked row value, I create a `js` for do this:

```js
document.getElementById("t_cov_e").value = this.cells[7].value;
document.getElementById("t_price_e").value = this.cells[5].value;
```

But when I try my code the select tag `t_price_e` populate correctly but `t_cov_e` does nothing. I checked the value passed and it is ok, even if I change the row with:

```js
document.getElementById("t_cov_e").value = "Test";
```

Nothing changes; when I look at my HTML the select tag `t_cov_e` does not display any default value.

How is this possible?
How can I set a default value to my select tag with `javascript`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: So on selecting an option from `t_cov_e` you want to set a default value in `t_price_e` ? Is that what you want  ?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Assuming that you want a default value in dropdown, `document.getElementById("t_cov_e").value = "Test";` cannot work as `Test` is not option in `select`

Comment: document.getElementById("t_cov_e").value = "OS"; works.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set the value you can use this

```js
window.onloaded=load();

function load(){
var leaveCode = document.querySelector('#t_cov_e');
leaveCode[3].selected = true;
}
```

working demo:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/4Lwr06tj/22/

but why are you trying to set `this.cells[7].value` while there are only 5 cells